# Flask-mail create independent mail instead of email thread

Tags: python, flask, gmail-api, email-verification, flask-mail

I'm creating an email verification service and using Flask-mail. Whenever a user Signs up, I'm sending a unique validation link to verify the email address.

As per my code, the email subject (verify your email address...) remains the same while the verification link changes every time a new mail is sent. However, every time I send a **new mail to the same recipient**, the email ends up as an **email thread** in the user's gmail inbox.

From the attached image, you can see that the *three sent mails have become an email thread*.

How do I configure the Flask-mail API to send independent mails instead of creating an email thread?

I was going through the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/) and StackOverflow but couldn't find any solution.

[image]

---

**Code for reference**

```
mail = Mail(app=current_app)

# embedding a new validation link in the message body.
message_body = VERIFY_ACC_BODY.format(url_for('auth.verify_user_email', 
user_token=token, _external=True))

email_notification = Message(subject=VERIFY_ACC_SUBJECT,
                                 recipients=[user.user_id],
                                 body=message_body)

# creates email threads instead of independent emails. Why?
mail.send(email_notification)
```

---

**NB**: Please don't suggest changing the Email Subject for every mail. That's not the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you are trying to combat a Gmail feature that is largely based on the email's subject line. [More about this](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/5900).

> Emails are grouped if each message meets the following:
>
> - The same recipients, senders, or subject as a previous message.
> - A reference header with the same IDs as a previous message.
> - Sent within one week of a previous message.
>
> To prevent grouped emails:
>
> - Create a new subject for each message that you don’t want to group.
> - Send each message with a unique reference header value that doesn’t match a  previous message.

You could attempt: `extra_headers={"references": "{{ unique value }}"}` in your `email_notification = Message(...)` to try to avoid Gmail's threading feature.

Comment: Welcome to the community. I have upvoted your answer. I will try to figure out the extra_header arguments.

Comment: I have just left my answer for this question to help folks in future. Basically, Subject is used as an identifier in gmail (if the mail has same recipients). I chose not to mark your answer as accepted since there isn't a solution for this problem to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

NB: This answer is valid as of April 11, 2019. In future, `Gmail` or `Flask-mail` might change few policies or update their APIs. Therefore, this answer may not be valid in future.

---

I'm just leaving this answer out here hoping that it could save some time for folks in future.

In addition to @VizslaVizsla's answer, the setting the `extra_headers={...}` doesn't seem to work despite repeated testing. The emails get grouped nevertheless.

A [similar question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16095/gmail-grouping-messages-with-the-same-subject) was posted on StackExchange a few years ago.

So far, I've tried various different `extra_headers`. None of them prevented grouping.

```
from uuid import uuid4
# uuid used to generate a unique identifier for every mail.

extra_headers={'references': str(uuid4())} # Didn't work
extra_headers={'Message Id': str(uuid4())} # Didn't work
extra_headers={'Message-Id': str(uuid4())} # Gmail message id. Didn't work
```

It looks like you must change the subject title or recipients to prevent grouping. I haven't tested by changing CC or BCC list though. If you folks have the time or patience, feel free to test that and post your observations here.